# How to set custom tooltip design in HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I've bar graph of HighCharts in my application. Tooltip given by the highcharts is working fine. But I want to add some more data to the tooltip.

Please consider the following image. That contains the current graph.
[image]

In the tooltip, it is showing the counts of New Ticket and Completed counts. But I want to show them by grouping them into some other values.

For example, I have different `Zones`. Now I want to group the counts based on Zones. Please consider the attachment below.

[image]

Here Zone wise counts and Zones too are of dynamic values. Will get Zones wise counts if data available, other wise will not get Zones at all.

Is it possible to get the tooltip in the required format?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `formatter` function for a tooltip to create tooltip structure you need. For example:

```
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function() {
            let header = '<span style="font-size: 10px">' +
                this.x + '</span><br/>';

            let zone1 = '<span style="color: red">Zone - 1:</span> <br/>';
            let zone2 = '<span style="color: red">Zone - 2: <br/>';
            let zone3 = '<span style="color: red">Zone - 3: <br/>';

            this.points.forEach(function(point) {
                zone1 += '<span style="margin-left: 15px; color: ' + point.color + '">' +
                    point.series.name + ': ' + point.y + '</span><br/>';
                zone2 += '<span style="margin-left: 15px; color: ' + point.color + '">' +
                    point.series.name + ': ' + point.point.zone2 + '</span><br/>';
                zone3 += '<span style="margin-left: 15px; color: ' + point.color + '">' +
                    point.series.name + ': ' + point.point.zone3 + '</span><br/>';
            });

            return header + zone1 + zone2 + zone2;
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2svpz0ug/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter